# White background in Boolean columns at JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` where two columns are `Boolean` and I use this method to recognize the type of data:

```
public Class getColumnClass(int column){
    if ((getValueAt(0, column)) == null){
        return super.getColumnClass(column);

    }
```

The data is shown perfectly like a `CheckBox`, but the background is white, unlike the rest of the columns:

[image: White background]

Just let me know if you need some more code. **I'm using the `NimbusLookAndFeels` (don't know if it really matters)

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I found already an answer for my question in this post:

[JTable - Boolean Cell Type - Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601994/jtable-boolean-cell-type-background)

I don't know how I can set it like duplicate question